# APEX 19.2 - Run validations before dynamic action

Tags: validation, oracle-apex-19.1

Have a page to create a login, where the user name is an email address. None of the validations run prior to a Dynamic Action on button press.

Written, and very much needed validations are:

- **Email format:** regular expression indicating if the entered email is formatted correctly (i.e. have not forgotten part of the email). This same email format validation works correctly on other pages.
- **Password:** multiple validations for password - minimum of 8 characters, contain both Upper and lower case, has at least one number, and at least one special character

This is PL/SQL code for the Dynamic Action which needs to run after the validations - when there are no errors on the page. Have set the Server Side Condition for this dynamic action to "Inline Validation Errors NOT displayed". However because this runs first, there are never validation errors. This dynamic action calls a DB package procedure and sends a verification code by email to the entered user name (email address):

```
 declare
  vCode varchar2(5) := dbms_random.string('X',5);
 begin
   :P3_SENTCODE := vCode;
   MY_PKG.EmailCode(v('P3_USERNAME'), vCode);
 end;
```

The email is sent, however **none** of the validations run at all. It will even send to a non-existent email such as: help123@test (not formatted correctly, no entry of what comes after "test"). How do I run the validations **before** the dynamic action which sends an email?

Comment: Why do you need to do his in a dynamic action?  This sort of thing is normally done in a page submit process.

Comment: It's done in a DA because the page is not yet submitted until after a user enters the code sent to them by email.

Comment: Wondering if I need to update the DA PL/SQL code to contain all the validations? Do something like adding a raise_application_error?

Comment: You could submit the page twice? Once to send the email, and a second time when the user enters the code.

Comment: But yes you could replicate the valdiation logic in the DA PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validations run okay after the dynamic action, and when a user clicks on the create button. Then the information is there prior to submitting. Was really trying to alter the dynamic action PL/SQL to include validations, however that did not work. Thank you all for looking at this and your help!